# Does anyone make a USB to DB9 console adapter that is win7 compatible?

Tags: untagged

I am in the process of remediating some aged documentation with current data, and as part of that I need to console into a ton of switches. I had had a belkin adapter in our datacenter but it appears to have grown legs. Looking at the same part, it appears that they are not compatible with windows 7 - this is a problem, as corporate mandate is that we all use windows 7. I can't seem to hunt down which is sturdy AND supports windows 7.

Comment: I just checked, http://www.altavista.com/ is still working!

Comment: I highly recommend getting a [USB<->Serial adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=PL-2303%20adapter&tbm=shop) based on the Prolific PL-2303 chip. You'd need a [driver for Vista/7](http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp?ID=31), but every other OS has built-in drivers (Linux, OSX, BSD, Solaris, XP/2000)

Comment: Thanks for the smartass replies, except if you read the question the real issue was that most of the cables aren't supported in windows 7. Maybe it would be better in superuser, but your snarky feedback was completely unconstructive and bypassed the actual question. Had I not googled, I wouldn't have been able to notice that. Try reading comprehension instead of making snide remarks next time.

Comment: @Matthew - mine is that I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Cables-to-Go-USB-to-DB9-Serial-Adapter/297778.aspx

That's the one I use and it works just fine on Win7 Enterprise 64 bit.

But it did require a driver download after plugging it in to get it to be recognized properly in Device Manager.

http://www.cablestogo.com/help/ctg_drivers.asp